# How to implement a copy participant in eclipse to generate a new file along with other related files with same name within the same directory?

Tags: plugins, swt, eclipse-rcp, copy-paste, eclipse-gef

I'm trying to implement a copy participant and things work quite well when I copy a resource to another location. However, things does not work if I do a copy+paste into the same directory. Eclipse will happily suggest a new name for the file, but it seems that I cannot get a pointer to the new name in my implementation of the CopyParticipant.

What I see is, that org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.CopyResourceChange.getNewResourceName() asks for the new name but the participant appears to be already done with its job at that point in time. Did I miss something?